# Pyramid .bat not finding PSERVE

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a web system developed in Pyhton 2.7.7 with Pyramid 1.5.1 (I know it's quite old, but it's an enterprise system), and I'm trying to install the same system in another server.

I have installed all the libraries and created the project, but when I call the pserve command (`call ..\Scripts\pserve production.ini --reload`), it says:

```
Starting subprocess with file monitor
c:\v2\Scripts\python.exe: can't open file 'C:\v2\Scripts\pserve': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I don't know what to do because the `path` is correct.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Where did you install your project on your system? In your system Python or a virtual environment? You should use a virtual environment.

Comment: It's installed in a virtual env

Comment: Then you can call pserve via `path/to/pserve production.ini` in your virtual environment. From the root of your project, that may be `env/bin/pserve`, where `env` is the name of your virtual environment.